# Sampling without Replacement and Non-uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

There are $N$ items, numbered $1 \ldots N$. The probability of selecting item $i$ in one draw is $p_i$. Items are drawn without replacement, so after each draw we need to do a re-normalization. Now, could you please tell me how to write down the probability of drawing $i$ in $k$ ($k \le N$) attempts? Even an approximate solution is good. Thanks!

Comment: random sampling? drawing at least once? exactly once? something else? .. Is this an exercise for a class?

Comment: I think the sampling without replacement implies you can only draw $i$ once.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes. Only draw i once. Not an exercise for a class. Basically, one can write a program to enumerate all combinations. But it is very slow. Are there any closed form solution or approximated solution? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the multivariate Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution. ie weighted balls, multiple colors, multiple draws. [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution)

Comment: @KitterCatter Thanks! This is what I am looking for. Please post an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the multivariate Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution. ie weighted balls, multiple colors, multiple draws.[wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution)

I did try to find something analytic, but even in simple cases this problem becomes increasingly complicated. I would advise looking at some of the packages in the link.

Answer (score 2):

A *long* comment which I have have had to post as an answer. I  have
no objection if some kindly Moderator converts it into a series of
comments on the main question.

Your question is essentially unanswerable in one sense.

You have told us that the probability of drawing the $i$-th object on the first draw is $p_i$.  In the general scheme of *drawing* **with** *replacement*, the probability of drawing the $i$-th object remains the same on all further draws.

However, in the general scheme of *drawing* **without** *replacement*
(which you want to consider), there is no immediate answer to the question: what is the
probability of drawing the $i$-th object on the second draw? the third draw? etc. There is also the question whether we want the *unconditional*
probability of drawing the $i$-th object on the second draw, or the
*conditional* probability of drawing the $i$-th object on the second draw *given* that the first draw resulted in the $j$-th object being drawn?

*One* possibility to consider is that the (conditional) probabilities are obtained by *re-normalizing* the probabilities
of the *remaining* balls at each step.  That is, we write
\begin{align}
P(i_i) &= p_{i_1},\\
P(i_1, i_2) &= p_{i_1}\cdot \frac{p_{i_2}}{1-p_{i_1}}\\
P(i_1, i_2,i_3) &= p_{i_1}\cdot \frac{p_{i_2}}{1-p_{i_1}}
\cdot \frac{p_{i_3}}{1-p_{i_1}-p_{i_2}}\\
P(i_1, i_2,i_3,i_4) &= p_{i_1}\cdot \frac{p_{i_2}}{1-p_{i_1}}
\cdot \frac{p_{i_3}}{1-p_{i_1}-p_{i_2}}
\cdot \frac{p_{i_4}}{1-p_{i_1}-p_{i_2}-p_{i_3}}
\end{align}
and so on. But there could be other kinds of assumptions that might be
made about what happens on successive draws, and so unless *you*
specify what the probabilities are on successive draws, w=your 
question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comments. I agree that the original problem description is unclear. I have added renormalization to the description now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an approximation, I will propose one. It's not perfect: it requires additional reasonable assumptions; I won't prove it's accurate; I'm not sure it's a valid pmf.

If $N$ is large, $K << N$, and the $p_j's$ are small, then drawing once gives a probability of $p_j$. The next draw will be only slightly better than $p_j$, etc. The draws are not independent, but are not too dependent. So I would approximate drawing the desired event in $K$ trials as drawing one sample in a poisson with $\lambda=K \times p_j$.

This gives you a probability of $K \times p_j \times  e^{-K p_j}$.

Comment: Thanks! Under these assumptions, I guess we can directly use 1 - (1 - p_j)^K?

Comment: You could compare both of these approximations with the Wallenius mentioned by @Kitter Catter, for the values of K, N, and $p_j$ you expect. In R there is a package BiasedUrn.